# Missing failed_jobs exist on redis-cli with Laravel Horizon

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-horizon

Our failed jobs table is empty, but we can see the missing jobs and job_id's with redis-cli

`keys *` returns a list of all the failed jobs

```
...
16578) "horizon:production1335842"
16579) "horizon:production1335474"
16580) "horizon:production1267827"
16581) "horizon:production1259905"
16582) "horizon:production1267420"
16583) "horizon:production1262883"
16584) "horizon:production1258641"
16585) "horizon:production1337095"
...
```

`hget "horizon:production1335842"` will return the details of the failed job

If I do

```
zrange "horizon:productionrecent_failed_jobs" 0 -1
```

I can see a list of the failed job IDs

```
...
16578) "1335842"
16579) "1335474"
...
```

How can I get failed jobs in redis back into the queue?

Also, in horizon.php instead of

```
'queue' => ['production', 'mail'],
```

should I have

```
'queue' => ['production:', 'mail:'],
```

?

Comment: Does `php artisan queue:failed` produce any output?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the queue:failed table is empty. We had a couple of memory intensive jobs which forced us to restart the server

Comment: Are you using a database table to store the job information, i.e., one created with `php artisan queue:table`? I wouldn't expect that table to be emptied upon restarting the server. In any case, do you see the jobs if you go into Tinker and issue `resolve('Laravel\Horizon\Contracts\JobRepository')->getFailed();`?

Comment: yes, there were a few jobs with a huge amount of ID's for a large export queue, which maximized memory limit. Now jobs are limited to 25 jobs per minute, down from several 100 :S

Comment: Were you able to re-queue the jobs? Or are you still stuck?